# IBM Watson Visual Recognition: Received invalid status in 403 in getAllCollections response for guid (...) at endpoint (...)

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am using IBM Watson Visual Recognition for a custom model. I have uploaded my dataset as .zip files, which is fine so far. However, I cannot train the model. When I go on my Watson services, it says:

Error fetching custom collections: Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Recieved invalid status 403 in getAllCollections response for guid crn:v1:bluemix:public:watson-vision-combined:us-south:a/649b0335a5a44f6d80d1fd6909e466f9:8a71daa3-b0be-42ac-bb72-1473de835c19:: at endpoint https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/

When I try to train the model, it says:
 "Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Request Entity Too Large"

To the best of my knowledge, I have checked Google and StackOverflow for solutions, but didn't find any. I am using the Lite version. I only have one project, and one Visual Recognition instance. Please note that it worked for a different Visual Recognition model before, but later I could not use or access that model. So I deleted the older, trained model and tried to create a new one with the above mentioned error.
Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in Visual Recognition.
HTTP 403 is a standard HTTP status code communicated to clients by an HTTP server to indicate that access to the requested (valid) URL by the client is Forbidden for some reason.   It indicates some problem with your account access.

The "Request Entity Too Large" is a bit misleading, it happens sometimes when the error should be a 403 on POST requests, like training.

As a lite plan user, you may have used up your free credits for the month, for example.
You should double check that you are providing the correct credentials, and check the usage dashboard of your IBM Cloud account, which is described here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/billing-usage?topic=billing-usage-viewingusage

If this does not resolve your problem, you can open a support request here https://www.ibm.com/cloud/support

Comment: Thank you! I think I must've used up the Lite plan. The error message was indeed misleading. I will try again on February 1st.